# Why the push to "r" array not working properly in the loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, recursion, push

Why the following array doesn't push correctly in the loop to r?

If I change to `if((pivot + originArr[c]) <= 5)` instead of `if((pivot + originArr[c]) <= 3)`

My result is wrong:

```
[ [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ],
  [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ],
  [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ],
  [ 0, 2, 3 ],
  [ 1, 2, 3 ] ]
```

**Expected result should be`[ [ 0, 1, 2], [ 0, 1, 3], [ 0, 1, 4], [ 0, 2, 3 ] ]`**

If r is not empty, it will recursive and send the first iteration result to the function to do computation until the "r" is empty. It doesn't push individual group of array to "r" for every c loop.

```js
var data = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

function compute(originArr, filterArr) {
  var r = [];
  var arr;

  let firstLoop = false;
  if (filterArr.length == 0) {
    firstLoop = true;
    arr = originArr;
  } else {
    arr = filterArr;
  }

  arr.forEach(function(i, index) {
    
    var pivot;
    if (firstLoop) {
      pivot = index;
    } else {
      pivot = parseInt(i.slice(-1));
    }
    var nextIndex = pivot + 1;
    console.log(pivot, nextIndex);
    for (var c = nextIndex; c < originArr.length; c++) {
      let tempResult = [];
      console.log(c);
      if (pivot + originArr[c] <= 3) {
        if (firstLoop) {
          tempResult.push(index);
        } else {
          tempResult = i;
        }
        tempResult.push(c);
        console.log(tempResult);
        r.push(tempResult); // suppose to push [0,1], [0,2], [0,3], [1,2] for the first iteration
      }
    }
  });

  if (r.length > 0) {
    return compute(originArr, r);
  } else {
    return arr;
  }
}

console.log(compute(data, []));
//Final result should be [[0,1,2]]
```

Comment: Your variable `r` must be declared with `var` or `let`.

Comment: Same for `arr` by the way, and `c`. You will catch these problems more easily by enabling strict mode. Add this as the first line in your file: `"use strict";`

Comment: Your `r`, `arr` and `c` variables are undeclared. This is bad for a recursive function.

Comment: the "i" is an array from the second call of compute function.

Comment: What is the purpose of the function? Can you provide some inputs and expected outputs?

Comment: The input is an array [0,1,2,3,4,5]

Expected output is the group of number that is less or equal to 3. (the group with most number [[0,1,2]])

Comment: Oh my, `i` as a variable name for an array... Indeed.

Comment: Without this line r.push(tempResult), I will get  [0,1], [0,2], [0,3], [1,2]  for 4 of the temResult, wonder why I can't push these array into r.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found out the problem.

We can't clone the array like this

```
tempResult = i;
```

it will affect the reference 'i' after I have pushed the new number into the temResult.

So my solution is to change the cloning way to:

```
tempResult = [...i];
```

That cloning will not affects the reference.